# images disapper on scrolling in coverflowlayout

Tags: android, apache-flex

I am using the following code to create a horizontal list of images on Android using Flash Builder 4.6.

```
<s:layout>
<layouts:CoverflowLayout id="coverflow" selectedIndex="{list.selectedIndex}"
                         horizontalDistance="130" selectedItemProximity="50" 
                                 depthDistance="1" elementRotation="-75" focalLength="300"
                                 perspectiveProjectionX="-1" perspectiveProjectionY="-1"/>

</s:layout>
```

It shows a horizontal list of images. I am able to select the iamges when I click on them but when I swipe on the list, all the images disappear. Is it possible to prevent them from disappearing or add this swipe effect ?

Comment: What is this `CoverflowLayout`. It's not part of the Flex 4 SDK.

Comment: I was working on an old code developed by someone else. Probably I should look if its coming from an external library.